# Having an index on a database field that is VARCHAR can increase the speed in the insertions?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing, unique

I have two tables in my database: page and link. In each one I define that the URL field is UNIQUE because I don't want repetead URLs.

Being a UNIQUE field, it automatically have an index? Creating an index for these field can speed up the insertions? What is the most appropriate index for a VARCHAR field?

Having a lot of rows can slow the insert because this UNIQUE field? At the moment, I have 1,200,000 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, adding a UNIQUE constraint [will create an index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#AEN2445):

> Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique btree index on the column or group of columns used in the constraint.

This won't speed up your INSERTs though, it will actually slow them down:

1. Every insert will have to be checked (using the index) to ensure that uniqueness is maintained.
2. Inserts will also update the index and this doesn't come for free.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned speed up considering that it was UNIQUE without the use of a index, but now I know that a index is used, but the btree index is the best for varchar?

Comment: @Renato: ["Currently, only B-tree indexes can be declared unique."](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/indexes-unique.html) So if you need a UNIQUE constraint then B-tree is your only choice. In general, I'd say it depends on your data so start with the default and then profile and test various options.

Answer (score 2):

Logically speaking, a constraint is one thing, and an index is another. Constraints have to do with data integrity; indexes have to do with speed.

Practically speaking, most dbms implement a unique constraint by building a unique index. A unique index lets the dbms determine more quickly whether the values you're trying to insert are already in the table.

I suppose an index on a VARCHAR() column might speed up an insert under certain circumstances. But generally an index slows inserts, because the dbms has to

- check all the constraints, then
- insert the data, and finally
- update the index.

A suitable index will speed up updates, because the dbms can find the rows to be updated more quickly. (But it might have to update the index, too, which costs you a little bit.)

PostgreSQL can tell you which indexes it's using. See [EXPLAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-explain.html).

Answer (score 1):

Usually b-tree/b+tree index is the most common indexes, and most likely inserts and updates are slower with these indexes, whereas selection of single row, selection of ranges and ORDER BY (ascending in most cases) would be very quick. This is because this index is ordered and so insertion would have to find out where to insert, instead of just inserting it at the end of the table. In the case of a clustered index, insertion/updates are even worse because of page splits.

Being unique would probably make it a bit slower since it has to scan more rows to make sure it is unique.

Also varchar is generally not the best choice for indexes if you are looking for optimal performance, integer is much much faster if it can be used. So there really is no 'best' index for varchar, each index has its own strengths and weaknesses and theres always a tradeoff. It really depends on the situation and what you plan to do with it, do you only need inserts/updates? Or do you also need to make selections? These are the things you need to ask.